# Is there any way to use Google Analytics in a blackberry java app?

Tags: blackberry, google-analytics

i have the need of use ga for a bb java app . And i have been searching but i havent found any way to do it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something that runs:

http://kenai.com/projects/googleanalyticsme/

It can run with J2ME ergo it can runs onto Blackberry

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

http://code.google.com/p/ga-api-java-samples/